# Software that would convert Google documents to .docx

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-api

Is there a way to convert a Document that you create in Google Docs to .docx or .odt?

Edit: To be more specific, I am looking for a software that would be able to archive this.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic in this site. Try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Google Docs allows you to download the file: File > Download As. Is this not sufficient for what you need? .docx and .odt are both supported file formats for download.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

*(following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137708/software-that-would-convert-google-document-to-docx/137719?noredirect=1#comment126304_137719))*

To convert Google Docs  en masse in a folder:

1. Select all of them using <kbd>Shift</kbd> or/and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> *(<kbd>Cmd</kbd> for Mac)*
2. Right click and select `Download`.
3. The Drive automatically converts all the selected documents and packs them into a ZIP file.
4. Save the created zip file. When un-zipped all files are converted.

---

**Original answer**

You can do that right from within the menu in Google Sheets.

`File` > `Download` > `pick one`

[image]

Comment: Can this be done using an API? I only found similar endpoint for drive, but i need to convert files...

Comment: Please keep in mind that questions about desktop software or web application recommendation, are [considered off-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site. At the risk of being downvoted or even closed, I suggest you limit your question to Google Drive.